# What am I missing when making the exact same POST request on browser as I am in Postman that's making it fail?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

In Postman - I'm logging in successfully with login endpoint and after that, I do a file upload which works successfully with the endpoint below.  The id and file path get stored successfully in the db.  I can conclude that in Postman - after logging in and only attaching one piece of form data (which's the file being uploaded) that the id and email display correct values in Postman. I can confirm it because if I run the `dd($id, $email);`, the correct values are returned.  I'm not attaching email and user id like how I am in my front end code

However, on the browser - I'm trying to send up user id and email but I keep getting a 500 error in the logs that says: `"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"`.

When I try it on the browser, I'm trying to use access token which would hopefully detect who the user is but that isn't working.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my frontend code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
        this.getId(id);
        this.getEmail(email);
    }

    getId(id) {
        console.log("inside getId()");
        this.setState({id: id}, () => console.log(this.state.id));
    }

    getEmail(email) {
        console.log("inside getEmail");
        this.setState({email: email}, () => console.log(this.state.email));
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] });
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        formData.append('file', file);

        axios.post('http://myendpoint/api/auth/dash', formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's my backend controller code (using Laravel Passport):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $id = $request->user()->id;
        $email = $request->user()->email;

        // dd($id, $email);

        if (($user = Auth::user()) !== null) {
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $id,
                'email' => $email
            ];

            DB::table('my.db')->insert($data);
            return response()->json($user);
        }
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Here's login method in controller:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You don't `append()` the id, email, or accessToken on the `FormData` object. If you don't add them they won't be sent

Comment: @PatrickEvans ah ok, so how would I add them?  This is where I've been stuck for a long time :(. I want it to be sent the database can know which user uploaded the file

Comment: same way you add the file, `formData.append("id",this.state.id)` and same for the other values

Comment: I think that's what was meant by "after logging in and only attaching one piece of form data (which's the file being uploaded) that the id and email display correct values in Postman." I'm assuming that when this form is submitted the user should already be logged in and the email and id should come from the session. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jordan yes exactly!

Comment: @PatrickEvans oh yeah I've tried that before but I still get the above 500 error

Comment: How is your session handled? Does the `accessToken` need to be sent in the request for the framework to use the correct session? If so that has to be either set in a cookie or in the formData (again depending on the config of the framework)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I've posted my login method from my auth controller.  I don't think it needs to be sent but not too sure :\

Comment: I've never worked with passport before, but I know in non-passport laravel the user comes from ```Auth::user()``` like in your ```if```. Does that ```if``` cause any errors? If not what happens if you try to get the user with ```Auth``` instead of via ```$request```?

Comment: @Jordan I tried that and I'm not getting an error in Postman but in the browser I'm getting that same 500 error.